# Open android or ios application from a web page

Tags: javascript

I want my website to redirect to a specific app in the Google Play or App store

Works great with a link the user is actively clicking on:

But if I am detecting the device with javascript and trying to redirect the browser automatically  and the user is redirected to the Google Play or App store website instead of the Google Play or App store app on the phone.

```
 var OSName = "Unknown OS";
 if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Win") != -1) OSName = "Windows";
 if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mac") != -1) OSName = "Macintosh";
 if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Linux") != -1) OSName = "Linux";
 if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Android") != -1) OSName = "Android";
 if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("like Mac") != -1) OSName = "iOS";

 if(OSName == "Android"){
       const url = "intent://my_host#Intent;scheme=my_scheme;action=my_action;end";
       window.location.replace(url);

 }else if(OSName == "iOS"){
        setTimeout(function(){  
          window.location.href = "https://apps.apple.com/app/instagram/id389801252?vt=lo";
        },250);

 }else{
     alert('app not found');
 }
```

Is there any way to open app or change this behavior?

Comment: I would guess that this is a browser/device security feature specifically to prevent apps being opened without direct user interaction, in which case, it's unlikely there's a reliable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you need to use a special URL scheme that is supported by the Google Play or App store app on the user's device.

For example, on Android, you can use the following URL scheme to redirect the user to the Google Play app:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>
```

Replace `<package_name>` with the package name of the app you want to redirect the user to.

For iOS, you can use the following URL scheme to redirect the user to the App store app:

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/<app_name>/<app_id>
```

Replace `<app_name>` with the name of the app you want to redirect the user to, and `<app_id>` with the app's ID in the App store.

In your code, you can use these URL schemes as follows:

```
if(OSName == "Android"){
   const url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>";
   window.location.replace(url);

}else if(OSName == "iOS"){
   const url = "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/<app_name>/<app_id>";
   window.location.replace(url);
}
```

This should redirect the user to the app in the Google Play or App store on their device, if the app is installed. If the app is not installed, the user will be redirected to the app's page in the Google Play or App store where they can download the app.

Note that this will only work on mobile devices. On desktop devices, the user will be redirected to the app's page in the Google Play or App store website instead.

Comment: if(OSName == "Android"){
                const url = "market://details?id=app.abcd";
                window.location.replace(url);
}   not working above solution

Comment: @SagarGajera I edited the answer since "market://" no longer works, as Google has deprecated it in favor of the play.google.com URL.